# How can I send a respond message if no argument is given?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a bot with multiple commands other commands work flawlessly, but my `say` command it is having troubles when I type

> say [message]

it sends the message correctly, but when there is not message I'm getting an error, so I decided to add an `if statement` so when there is no message it send the message `"Sorry I can't send an empty message"` which does now work.

Here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: 'When someone types ",say[message]" the bot says the message',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
        message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        message.channel.send(sayMessage);
        if(sayMessage == sayMessage.length(0)){
            message.channel.send("Sorry i can'y send an empty message");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for an `empty string` in an easier way:

```js
if(!sayMessage) return message.channel.send(`I can't send a empty message`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is found in the following lines:

```
message.channel.send(sayMessage);
if(sayMessage == sayMessage.length(0)){
    message.channel.send("Sorry i can'y send an empty message");
}
```

The issue is the control flow of the program, so which lines of code are executed at what time. In the current state of your program, the line `message.channel.send(sayMessage);` executes under any conditions. Only after that line is already executed, you test if the `sayMessage` string is empty.

To fix your code, you need to include the `message.channel.send(sayMessage);` line in an if statement. An example of that would be:

```
if(sayMessage.length === 0) {
    message.channel.send("Sorry i can'y send an empty message");
} else {
    message.channel.send(sayMessage);
}
```

As @Toasty mentioned in their answer, you might also want to look into different ways of checking if a string is empty.

**Full fixed code**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: 'When someone types ",say[message]" the bot says the message',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
        message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        if(sayMessage.length === 0) {
            message.channel.send("Sorry i can'y send an empty message");
        } else {
            message.channel.send(sayMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**

I have personally not tested the code, but based on my answer the logic behind the solution to your problem should be clear.